# Primeiro item retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, array, string

Estou tentando imprimir no *inner* um `split`, porém, após passar pelo `for`, o primeiro valor retorna como `undefined`, poderiam me indicar o que poderia ser?

```js
function parteTexto() {
  var teste;
  var texto = document.getElementById("caixa").value;
  var textoSplit = texto.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0, j = textoSplit.length; i < j; i++) {
    teste += textoSplit[i] + "<br/>"

  }
  document.getElementById("mostrar").innerHTML = teste;
}
```

```html
<input id="caixa" type="text">
<button onclick="parteTexto()">Analisar</button>
<div id="mostrar"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

O valor de `teste` é `undefined` inicialmente, e quando você concatena com `teste+= ...`, esse `undefined` é convertido para string e concatenado com `textoSplit[i]`.

Para resolver, inicialize `teste` como string vazia:

```
var teste = '';
```

Comment: Obrigada! Era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

Quando você cria uma variável sem iniciar ela, o valor padrão é:

```
undefined
```

Se quiser confirmar, abra o Google Chrome, entre no console de programador e teste esse comando Javascript:

```js
var x;console.log(x)
```

Você vai ver que ele vai imprimir exatamente o undefined.

Caso você inicie ela com uma string vazia "":

```js
var x="VAZIO";console.log(x)
```

Vazio é só um exemplo do que vai  acontecer, óbvio que você vai substituir a palavra vazio por nada, apenas duas aspas.